# Como sumo datos de una columna de tabla en C# y SQL Server con Entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Estoy trabajando con c# en visual studio y entity framework, soy novato en esto. Lo que necesito es sumar una columna de una tabla de sql server. Habia pensado en crear una lista con todos esos numeros y luego sumarlos. Pero no se como hacer esto. Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradeceria!

Comment: Buenas, para poder ayudarte debes agregar mas detalles. Por ejemplo tu codigo o la tabla con la columna que quieras  sumar

Comment: si lo resolviste seria un buen gesto explicar como?

Comment: Perdon, tambien soy novato aca. Lo resolvi antes de ver tu respuesta pero de la misma manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es simple solo tienes que usar el metodo de extension de linq

[Enumerable.Sum Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.7.2)

algo como lo siguiente

```
var result = dbcontext.NombeEntidad.Sum(x=> x.Propiedad);
```

en el lambda indicas cual es la propiedad que vas a sumar

Comment: Esta solucion es exactamente lo que buscaba y funciona perfecto, gracias!